# Issue in Serial Communication

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have written a code in c# for receiving data through serial communication and display it in a text box. I am able to do that. But I am receiving data in following format, e.g.

1234 2345 3456 5667
or

every byte in next line..
But I want that every incoming byte should overwrite the previous byte and in the text box we should see just 1 byte and then another byte overwriting the previous one.

Please suggest how to do that?

```
private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    RxString = SerialPort.ReadExisting(); 
    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText)); 
}

private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtIncomingData.AppendText(RxString);
}
```

Comment: I feel like I've seen this *exact* question a couple months ago.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending every received data to your textbox! that is an expected behavior. You should rather change your `textBox.Text` value every time you want to display a new received data.

Change your `DisplayText` method from :

```
private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtIncomingData.AppendText(RxString);
}
```

to

```
private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtIncomingData.Text = RxString;
}
```

P.S: I am assuming that `txtIncomingData` is a textBox control, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Yes, txtIncomingData is a textbox. I shall try it this way. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, I tried it by using txtIncomingData.Text = RxString;
But its not working.
Its giving just one first byte and no data in textbox after it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below works, but it gives blank bytes in between data.

```
      SerialPort serialPort;  

     private delegate void SetTextDeleg(string text);  

     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
     {  
           serialPort= new SerialPort("COM6", 4800, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);  
           serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;  
           serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);  
           serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;  
           serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;  
           serialPort.Open();  
 }  

 private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
 {  
       try  
       {  
            if(!serialPort.IsOpen)  
                 serialPort.Open();                     
       }  
       catch (Exception ex)  
       {  
            MessageBox.Show("Could not open Serial Port");  
       }  
 }  

 void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)  
 {  
      Thread.Sleep(500);  
      string data = serialPort.ReadLine();  
      this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextDeleg(si_DataReceived), new object[] { data });  
 }  

 private void si_DataReceived(string data)  
 {  
       txtIncomingData.Text = data.Trim();  
 }
```